# Does mxGraph support drawing using HTML canvas instead of SVG?

Tags: mxgraph

I was reading that when it comes to drawing diagrams in the Web there are several options, two of them are SVG and through HTML canvas, which have differences in performance.
I know mxGraph do drawings on a SVG by default, is there an option to draw using HTML canvas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MxGraph: Is it possible to render a graph in HTML without SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116136/mxgraph-is-it-possible-to-render-a-graph-in-html-without-svg)